# Mac - service doesn't start at boot after launchctl load

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, plist, autostart, launchctl

On my mac1.metal ec2 instance. I have a plist at ~/Library/LaunchAgents

```
ec2-user@ip-10-xxx-x-xxx ~ % ls -la ~/Library/LaunchAgents
-rw-r--r--  1 root      staff  1333 Mar  5 22:06 com.buildkite.buildkite-agent.plist
```

the service would run after running

```
sudo launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.buildkite.buildkite-agent.plist
```

and I can see it when I do `com.buildkite.buildkite-agent`

But when I reboot the instances the service would not restart. I thought launchctl load should achieve that?

Comment: Why the owner of plist is root and the file is placed in the users launch agent folder.

Comment: Change the owner of the file and launch it without sudo. It should work.